# Try to load a filebody from a file - Android

Tags: java, android, file, io

I try to upload a file from the selection of end user on Android.
The user choose is file and I upload it to a web service. There is a sample of my code.
The thing I don't understand is, if I choose a picture from the gallery there is no problem. but if I choose a file from the storage, I get an exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:

/content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/ .... open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Could you please help me?

```
case PICK_FILE:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the Uri of the selected file
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        try {
            // Get the path
            String path = FileGetPath(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            if(path==null){
                File f = new File(uri.toString());
                path = f.getAbsolutePath();
            }
            File file = new File(path);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(DomainToCall() + _uploadHandler);

            MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            entityBuilder.addPart("picture", new FileBody(file));
            post.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is not in image vs file 
problem is about picking a path

following code may help you

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
        selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

File f = new File(filePath);
```

use that f to pass in your multipart
i have not tried it for file i just tried it for image only
please try to use that and tell me if it work